# Climax of the film Encanto

Tags: plot-explanation, encanto

Does Mirabel get special powers at the end of the film *Encanto*? How does everyone get their powers back even after the candle is gone.

The candle is the source of the miracles and the house. But soon after the harmony of the Madrigal family disappears the cracks become visible, and at last, the house collapsed. The candle flamed out, but after the rebuild, soon after Mirabel touched the door knob, the miracles were regained for all family members.

I could not understand why this was happening. So I started to read some reviews about the film but could find the answers to my doubts.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to the site.  I edited your question a little just to make it a little more clear. "inmates" usually means "prisoners" so I changed it to the "Madrigal family".

Comment: For what it is worth .... the story is an allegory about family and community rather than magic.  Her magic power was showing them that the magic comes from them and not the candle.  I'm not sure a literal answer of "what happened" or "did she get special powers" exists.

Comment: My interpretation is that Mirabel got the same power Abuela had: The power to sustain the miracle so that everyone else had their powers, and basically to be her heir.  But I have no actual sources for that, so I don't consider it an answer.

Comment: @Bobson Agree, this can clearly be seen also in the fact that she is able to give commands to the house, as Abuela does.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no (or possibly maybe). Mirabel certainly doesn't receive any *overt* gifts at the end of Encanto, but she does seem to have the same powers that Abuela manifested, e.g. sustaining the miraculous valley and providing the house (and her family) with magic.

In the tie-in novelisation we learn that her door, and the room behind it has remained entirely mundane. If we assume that having a magical bedroom door is an indicator of magical powers, having a *non*-magical bedroom door is an indicator of a lack of magical powers.

> The door that was so plain and ordinary is now magnificent. Isabela's flowers outline the frame. Luisa has added bright, strong colors. Antonio's animals are represented. There's a rainbow that could only be from Pepa. I see a little theater, per­fect for performing rats... thanks to Tío Bruno.
>
> I open the new door, and my room is more beautiful and fantastical than I ever could have imagined. You would never know that it used to be a plain nursery. A vine grows above the bed like a canopy. A chigüiro is curled up on my pillow like a stuffed animal. A heavy bookshelf is loaded with books. A cup of hot chocolate and a plate of arepas steams on the table. Everyone in my family has added a little something to my room.
>
> <sub><sup>[Encanto: A Tale of Three Sisters](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/57294673)</sup></sub>

Comment: Is the door to the house itself now considered her doorbell?

Comment: @magarnicle - I suspect we'll find out in the sequel